# Chrome Image Transform (image disappears)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently running into a problem with a website I'm developing. (web store) there a zoom function on the products when you hover over them. however in chrome this seems not to work (the image will disappear). In firefox and even in Internet explorer it seems to work fine.

here is a sample of what happens. in chrome the images will disappear when you hover over them. in any other (non web-kit I presume) browser it works without problems.

https://jsfiddle.net/pnvkeugs/

```
<div class="col product-block">
  <div class="image">
    <a class="img" a="#">
      <img src="http://www.ecdevelopment.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/hippie-flower.jpg" alt="Example" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.product-block:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #D4D4D4;
}
.product-block:hover .image .img img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-btransform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.product-block .image {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.product-block .image .img {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.product-block .image .img img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your CSS to add:

```
a.img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I'd actually use inline blocks directly for the parents (`div.image`) instead of using floats.

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/pnvkeugs/1/